# Device-specific overclock settings?

Tags: overclocking

I have a microSD card, loaded with `shairplay-sync` and Cirrus Logic Audio Card driver that is shared among two Pi's, one Model B rev 1.2 (I have one of those short format adapter modules that takes a microSD without sticking out of the Model B PCB) and one Pi 2 Model B.

`shairplay-sync` when compiled with `libsoxr` is **very** CPU intensive (e.g. streaming Ariana Grande's *Focus* from Apple Music via an iPhone running iOS 9.3.3 will almost guarantee to stutter on a Model 1 without overclock as `libsoxr` spikes the CPU, but nothing except network issues can affect the Pi 2)

It is not advisable to leave overclock settings as-is when moving from Pi 1 to Pi 2. How can I do this device-specific overclock settings?

Answer (score 1):

See section `Conditional filters` of [config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md) for the settings you can make in `/boot/config.txt`

This lets you use the same configuration on multiple Pis but tailor each configuration by

- Pi model
- attached HDMI monitor
- Pi serial number